# Screen blacks out in app designed with codename one

Tags: codenameone

I have made my app with [codename one](http://www.codenameone.com).

I faced this strange issue:

I left my phone idle for a while and went to do some work.

After say about 15 mins, my screen had gone black while my app was still running. 
SO when I activated the screen, all I got was a black screen. My app was nowhere to be seen.

The menu button also didn't work. I tried to again open the app, but again I got a black screen (the same state just got restored). So then I had to press the home button and force stop the app and then start it.

This behaviour is pretty arbitrary. I tried to reproduce it, but it's not something that happens all the time.

But, it does happen sometimes out of the blue.

What could be the reason for this? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds related to this:
http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/issues/detail?id=154&can=1&q=wake

I'm guessing you are talking about an Android device right?

The application keeps running when suspended on an Android device, if something happened while the application was suspended it might fail on wakeup. If you can reproduce this file a bug, with the way to reproduce it (including code).

You can use the crash reporting system for paying subscribers (see the developer guide).

You can also install the Android SDK and use DDMS to inspect the device and see what fails (ideally with a debug build).